# Avoid twig block output

Tags: symfony, twig

I have the following twig template

```
{%- block block1 -%}
    <div class="test">
        {{ block('block2') }}
    </div>
{%- endblock block1 -%}

{%- block block2 -%}
    <div>Test2</div>
{%- endblock block2 -%}
```

The Result is:

```
<div class="test">
        <div>Test2</div>
</div><div>Test2</div>
```

But should be:

```
<div class="test">
        <div>Test2</div>
</div>
```

I want todo something like the form template in symfony: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.7/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig

**UPDATE:**

The only solution would be to add an if false which looks not very nice:

```
{%- block block1 -%}
    <div class="test">
        {{ block('block2') }}
    </div>
{%- endblock block1 -%}

{% if false %}
    {%- block block2 -%}
        <div>Test2</div>
    {%- endblock block2 -%}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you want to define your blocks this way? Or put it in other words: You can simply define the second block inside the first block like this:

```
{%- block block1 -%}
    <div class="test">
        {%- block block2 -%}
            <div>Test2</div>
        {%- endblock block2 -%}
    </div>
{%- endblock block1 -%}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you separate the result you get in a different way, it will help you see what is happening:

```
// block1 with block2 inserted
<div class="test">
        <div>Test2</div>
</div>
// block2
<div>Test2</div>
```

i.e. when you define block2 it is not only inserted into block1, it is also rendered at the place where it is defined. You may try to build this functionality some other way, perhaps by using the `include` function

Comment: I know but how they do it in the symfony
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.7/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig

Comment: The form component uses a special twig loader which is different from the standard twig renderer to load these blocks from this file

Comment: how can I use this special twig loader?

Comment: if I add an if false around the second block it works but seems for me a bit to hacky. thx for your answer

Answer (score 1):

you have to add your form theme to render these custom blocks or like Carlos Granados saying you have to include other twig here.

Which link you are showing is symfony2 form theme which will render when form blocks will call and it is doing it because you tell symfony2 to do it. In your layout twig add file like this -

```
   {% form_theme form "UrBundle:Default:fields.html.twig" %}
```

it will be your file which will render your blocks - fields.html.twig, 
here you can define your blocks and then can access those in current like -

```
{% block block1 %}
   {{ parent() }}
{% endblock %}
```

it's out will be like you want [link](https://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#method-2-inside-a-separate-template)

Comment: so for none form templates this is not possible?

Comment: yes it is possible, form theme is to render html code based on called block, add your's block and you can call that after adding {% form_theme form "UrBundle:Default:fields.html.twig" %}

Comment: if I add an if false around the second block it works but seems for me a bit  hacky. thx for your answer

Answer (score 0):

In twig, the main template rendered will always render all of the blocks "included" in the template, even with `extends`. Instead you're attempting to create horizontal reuse blocks.

In order to produce your desired result, you would need to implement a [`{% use 'blocks.twig' %}`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/use.html)

This approach is highly subjective to what you intend to accomplish and is not typically needed in regular templates.

### Example https://twigfiddle.com/fwjpl8

```
{# main.html.twig #}
{% use 'info.blocks.twig' %}

{%- block content -%}
    {%- set data = { name: 'Test', place: 'Test2' } -%}
    {{ block('data') }}
{%- endblock -%}
```

```
{# info.blocks.twig #}
{%- block data -%}Data {{ data.name }} {{ block('data_place') }}{%- endblock -%}

{%- block data_place -%}{{ data.place }}{%- endblock -%}
```

Result:

```
Data test test2
```

---

Do keep in mind there are limitations on `use`.

> The `use` tag only imports a template if it does not extend another
>   template, if it does not define macros, and if the body is empty. But
>   it can use other templates.

So you can not do

```
{# main.html.twig #}
{% use 'info.blocks.twig' %}
```

```
{# info.blocks.twig #}
{% extends 'other.blocks.twig' %}

{%- block data -%}Data {{ data.name }} {{ block('data_place') }}{%- endblock -%}

{%- block data_place -%}{{ data.place }}{%- endblock -%}
```